# Pivot tables stopped working after upgrade to Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

An excel document with several pivot and lookup tables that previously worked under Office XP and 2003 has stopped working after upgrading to office 2007 (and linked stuff doesn't update any more either).

I originally assumed there's something disabled in 2007 that I need to turn back on, but after having opened it in Excel 2007 it no longer works in previous versions either.

Any idea what I'm missing, what Excel 2007 did and how I fix it?

Comment: What version of Excel is the spreadsheet saved in? 97-2003 (.xls) or 2007 (.xlsx)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article written by Microsoft explaining the differences between the Pivot Table formats within Excel.  It lists a table of possible outcomes based on the version of your spreadsheet and the version of the Pivot Table within the spreadsheet:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA101672981033.aspx

Comment: that chart indicates it should keep working, but it does not :(
The spreadsheets an xls and it "breaks" after simply opening it (in compatibility mode) in 2007 i.e. no changes, no save just exit